# Graceful shutdown of Varnish

Tags: apache, ubuntu, varnish

Been mucking around with Varnish 3 for hours - it's a lot of fun. I'm trying to figure out a way to 'gracefully stop' Varnish - meaning if I ever hit `sudo service varnish stop` I would like Apache to come back right up. Of course the idea is to just stop Varnish when crap hits the fan then peace is restored.

The issue is that Apache listens on 8080 now, so I've been trying to make Apache listen to both port 80 and 8080 - it doesn't seem to be the right way since it doesn't work!

`<VirtualHost *:80 127.0.0.1:8080>`

Is there a clever way to achieve this? Or is a command-line script the way to go? What about setting the TTL to 0?

Comment: proxy to both backends using nginx or haproxy (set apache as a backup backend if a varnish connection times out).

Comment: @Santa ideally without using any other products. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Considering how socket/port-binding works, you'd need something in front of both of them, though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done quite easily, but it involves some kind of reverse-proxy.

The one that Stack Exchange uses is [haproxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/), but [nginx](http://nginx.org/) also works, as do a bunch of other loadbalancers and reverse proxies.

#### haproxy config:

```
global
        maxconn 4096
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon
        log 127.0.0.1 local0 debug

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        retries 3
        option forwardfor
        maxconn 2000
        timeout connect 3s

frontend public
        bind *:80
        default_backend servers

backend servers
        balance roundrobin
        server varnish 127.0.0.1:5000 check inter 15s
        server apache  127.0.0.1:8080 backup
```

This will automatically route to apache if varnish hasn't responded, and will check for varnish returning every 15 seconds.

#### nginx config:

```
upstream backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:5000 fail_timeout=3s; # varnish
    server 127.0.0.1:8080 backup; # apache
}

server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }

}
```

This does pretty much the same thing. Also, you can do your SSL handling in these frontends and not have to care about varnish.

Due to the way that port-binding works, unless you have an external piece of software working with apache and varnish, you can't get them to switch ports if one isn't responding.